# Mock arr.map(&:to_s) with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Consider the following code with a `#map(&:to_s)` call:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.map(&:to_s)
```

You could mock it out like this

```
expect(arr).to receive(:map) { |arg|
  expect(arg).to receive(:to_s)
}.and_return(["some","values"])
```

**but this isn't very handy, and I use the shortcut alot in my code.**

> Is there a handy shortcut (or is it possible to create one?) for mocking out `map(&:to_s)` calls in RSpec?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of actual code whose tests include something like the above? It seems like you're mocking things at a much lower level than you should be.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend mocking at this level but if you really wanted to, you could create a shortcut as you asked like this

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
RSpec.configure do |config|
  include MockHelper
end

# spec/support/mock_helper.rb
module MockHelper
  def mock_map(array)
    expect(array).to receive(:map).and_return(['some', 'values'])
    array.map(&:to_s)
  end
end

# spec/some_folder/some_spec.rb
describe SomeSpec do
  it 'receives map(&:to_s)' do
    mock_map [1, 2, 3]
  end
end
```

But again, I think this would be better

```
it 'converts array to String Array' do
  expect([1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s)).to eq ['1', '2', '3']
end
```